# value of useState not being set on initial render

Tags: reactjs

I have the `isDesktop` boolean that should be set to true or false depending on the sceensize and this works however on initial render it doesn't set to true/false, how can I set this on intial render?

```
 const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false)
  const [isDesktop, setIsDesktop] = useState(window.innerWidth)

  console.log(isDesktop)
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", UpdateScrollPosition);
    window.addEventListener("resize", displayWindowSize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", UpdateScrollPosition);
  }, []);

  const UpdateScrollPosition = () => {
    const scrollPos = window.scrollY
    if( scrollPos < 520) {
      return setIsVisible(false)
    }else if (scrollPos >= 520 && scrollPos <= 1350) {
      return setIsVisible(true)
    }else if (scrollPos > 1350) {
      return setIsVisible(false)
    }
  }

  const displayWindowSize = () => {
    let w = window.innerWidth;
    if(w >= 500) {
      return setIsDesktop(true)
    } else {
      return setIsDesktop(false)
    }    
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.innerWidth` is not a boolean. If you intented to set it to true for a value other than `0` you can do:

```
const [isDesktop, setIsDesktop] = useState(!!window.innerWidth)
```

You can also compare it to your breakpoint:

```
const [isDesktop, setIsDesktop] = useState(window.innerWidth >= 500);
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to use `isDesktop` in the `UpdateScrollPosition` handler you need to unregister the old handler and register a new handler as a listener, when `isDesktop` has changed:

```
const UpdateScrollPosition = useCallback(() => {

    // this now depends on isDesktop
    console.log(isDesktop);

    // .... other code

}, [isDesktop]); // IMPORTANT: add isDesktop here as a dependency

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", UpdateScrollPosition);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", UpdateScrollPosition);
}, [UpdateScrollPosition]); // IMPORTANT: Add UpdateScrollPosition here as a dependency
```

What does this?:

`useCallback` will recreate your handler when the `isDesktop` dependency changes. Your effect will re-bind the handlers when `UpdateScrollPosition` changes (which is always the case when `isDesktop` changes as we added it as a dependency there).

Comment: I see thanks however I actually need it to e set true or false depending on the initial screens size

Comment: thanks that works great, and how can I then use `isDesktop` in `updateScrollPosition`? It currently keeps the original state and doesn't update

Comment: @tomharrison This is because you are binding the `UpdateScrollPosition` handler in a `useEffect` that is only executed once on mount (due to the empty dependency list). I will update my answer.

Comment: @tomharrison see my updated answer. You need to make sure your re-bind your listener when props or state the listener is using changes. If you forget this your listener will always be the old one, that was first registered with stale values in its closure. This is best achieved by using `useCallback` to define your handler and add its dependencies there and use the callback resulting from this as a dependency for your `useEffect` hook that registers the handler.